# Python: How to plot multiple columns in one histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am learning python and the thing I am stuck on is plotting a histogram based on the FLT column to indicate each of the filters. I have this data frame:

```html
    VARLIST:      MJD FLT  FIELD  FLUXCAL  FLUXCALERR     MAG  MAGERR  \
0       OBS:  55161.6   g    NaN  -62.016      23.428     NaN  -0.410   
1       OBS:  55176.6   g    NaN   -8.183      21.252     NaN  -2.820   
2       OBS:  55179.6   g    NaN    0.451      19.109  -4.134  46.053   
3       OBS:  55188.6   g    NaN  511.964      21.218 -11.773   0.045   
4       OBS:  55206.6   g    NaN  682.704      22.329 -12.086   0.036   
..       ...      ...  ..    ...      ...         ...     ...     ...   
259     OBS:  56659.6   z    NaN  193.577      44.434 -10.717   0.249   
260     OBS:  56662.6   z    NaN    2.728      30.422  -6.089  12.109   
261     OBS:  56667.7   z    NaN   51.009      30.915  -9.269   0.658   
262     OBS:  56681.5   z    NaN    8.945      30.450  -7.379   3.696   
263     OBS:  56754.3   z    NaN   12.488      60.586  -7.741   5.268   

     peakMJD  mag_zpt27.5  snr_zpt27.5  magerr_zpt27.5  
0    55206.6    23.018741    -2.647089       -0.410262  
1    55206.6    25.217719    -0.385046       -2.820441  
2    55206.6    28.364559     0.023601       46.014133  
3    55206.6    20.726901    24.128759        0.045009  
4    55206.6    20.414419    30.574768        0.035519  
..       ...          ...          ...             ...  
259  55206.6    21.782866     4.356506        0.249282  
260  55206.6    26.410389     0.089672       12.110811  
261  55206.6    23.230883     1.649976        0.658191  
262  55206.6    25.121049     0.293760        3.696892  
263  55206.6    24.758768     0.206120        5.268770
```

My goal is to plot the FLT columns but to indicate the different filters: g, i, r, and z. From searching up how to make a histogram, I can plot a fundamental one based on the MAG (Magnitude). Ideally, what I would want are 4 different colors to indicate the different filters. I am aware that the graph would have overlapping Mag by the filter, but I am okay with it as I need a visual, and I can zoom in if I have to.

The code I have below is what I have right now. It is fundamental now since I have been stuck looking at the documentation and getting nowhere. Something to note is that in the middle are a bunch of comments about my attempts. One was to iterate through each row and look at the filter and then graph, but I couldn't figure that out. The other idea was to create 4 new columns, one for each filter, and then graph each column. I got stuck and couldn't figure it out.

```html
#HISTOGRAM
def plot_histogram(source, data_file):
    if source == 'villar':
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(data_file)
        SnName_villar = filename[34:-6]

        # read in for clarifying info
        ps1_phot_info = pd.read_csv(data_file)

        ra_deg = ps1_phot_info.loc[2][0][11:19] #deg
        dec_deg = ps1_phot_info.loc[3][0][12:19] #deg
        final_z_villar = ps1_phot_info.loc[5][0][17:23] 

        # read in for data
        ps1_phot = pd.read_csv(data_file, skiprows=15, delim_whitespace=True)
        ps1_phot.drop(ps1_phot.tail(1).index,inplace=True)

        ps1_phot['peakMJD'] = ps1_phot.iloc[ps1_phot['FLUXCAL'].idxmax()]["MJD"] 
        
        # Calculate mag. Look at zeropoints (A. Villar = 32.5, YSE = 27.5)
        ps1_phot['mag_zpt27.5'] = np.array(-2.5*np.log10(np.abs(ps1_phot['FLUXCAL'])))+27.5
        ps1_phot['snr_zpt27.5'] = (ps1_phot['FLUXCAL'] / np.abs(ps1_phot['FLUXCALERR']))
        ps1_phot['magerr_zpt27.5'] = np.array(1.086 / ps1_phot['snr_zpt27.5'])



        mask = (ps1_phot['FLUXCAL'].notna()) #& (ps1_phot['FLUXCALERR'] <= 50) 
        ps1_masked = ps1_phot.loc[mask] #has mag obs and reasonable error

        print(ps1_masked)


        ps1_phot['peakMJD'] = ps1_phot.iloc[ps1_phot['FLUXCAL'].idxmax()]["MJD"] 
        print('here')
        print(ps1_phot)

        #Calculate mag. Look at zeropoints (A. Villar = 32.5, YSE = 27.5)
        ps1_phot['mag_zpt27.5'] = np.array(-2.5*np.log10(np.abs(ps1_phot['FLUXCAL'])))+27.5
        ps1_phot['snr_zpt27.5'] = (ps1_phot['FLUXCAL'] / np.abs(ps1_phot['FLUXCALERR']))
        ps1_phot['magerr_zpt27.5'] = np.array(1.086 / ps1_phot['snr_zpt27.5'])



        mask = (ps1_phot['FLUXCAL'].notna()) #& (ps1_phot['FLUXCALERR'] <= 50) 
        ps1_masked = ps1_phot.loc[mask] #has mag obs and reasonable error

        #print(ps1_masked)
        #ps1_phot['g_band'] = ps1_phot.iloc[ps1_phot['FLT']=='g']
        #print("THIS IS THE G BAND")
        #print(ps1_masked)
        #ps1_phot['r_band'] = ps1_phot.iloc[ps1_phot['FLT']=='r']
        #print("THIS IS THE R BAND")
        #print(ps1_masked)
        #ps1_phot['i_band'] = ps1_phot.iloc[ps1_phot['FLT']=='i']
        #print("THIS IS THE I BAND")
        #print(ps1_masked)
        #ps1_phot['z_band'] = ps1_phot.iloc[ps1_phot['FLT']=='z']
        #print("THIS IS THE Z BAND")
        #print(ps1_masked)
        
        #for pb in passbands:
        #    plt.hist(x=ps1_masked[''])

        #numpy.histogram(a, bins=10, range=None, normed=None, weights=None, density=None)[source]
        
        
        #passbands = ('g', 'r', 'i', 'z')
        #for pb in passbands:
        #    #x = passbands[pd]
            
        #    #blah blah code --> Plot histogram
        #    #errorbar only for scatter plot
        #    ax1.errorbar(x=ps1_masked[passbands[pd]]['MJD'] - ps1_masked[passbands[pd]]['peakMJD'], y=ps1_masked[passbands[pd]][f'{yaxis_is}'], yerr=ps1_masked[passbands[pd]][f'{yaxiserr_is}'],
        #    fmt='o', alpha=0.5, color='g', label=f'{x}-PS1')
        #ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')
        
        yaxis_is = 'mag_zpt27.5' # or FLUXCAL
        yaxiserr_is = 'magerr_zpt27.5' # or FLUXCALERR
        
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)

        ax1.set_ylabel('Observations', fontsize=16)
        ax1.set_xlabel('Mag', fontsize=16)
        ax1.tick_params(labelsize=12)
        ax1.set_title(f'{SnName_yse}, z_yse={final_z_yse}; {SnName_villar}, z_villar={final_z_villar}', fontsize=16)

        #Plot

        ps1_phot['mag_zpt27.5'].hist()
        plt.savefig(f"path/to/file/my_plot_{pb}.png")

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

        fig.savefig(f'./Villar_Data_Graphs/{SnName_villar}_{SnName_yse}_{yaxis_is}_Histogram.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)    
        plt.close(fig) 
    
    
    #Read all the files "fileV = sorted(glob.glob('./Villar/ps1_sne_zenodo/*.dat'))" and then supernova type (has the same) 
    # check the redshift to see if the are comparable (range +/- 0.1)
```

This is where I call the function above

```html
x = './Villar/ps1_sne_zenodo/PS1_PS1MD_PSc000186.snana.dat'
SnName_villar, final_z_villar, ps1_masked_g, ps1_masked_r, ps1_masked_i, ps1_masked_z = get_dataframes(source='villar', data_file=x, plot_color='c', sntype_label='VIa')

y = './Photpipe/yselc_v3_photoz/GPC1v3_2020add.snana.dat'
SnName_yse, final_z_yse, pp_phot_g, pp_phot_r, pp_phot_i, pp_phot_z = get_dataframes(source='yse', data_file=y, plot_color='b', sntype_label='VIa')

plot_villar_and_yse(SnName_villar, final_z_villar, ps1_masked_g, ps1_masked_r, ps1_masked_i, ps1_masked_z, 
              SnName_yse, final_z_yse, pp_phot_g, pp_phot_r, pp_phot_i, pp_phot_z)


plot_histogram(source='villar', data_file=x)
#Call and plot histogram function
```

Please let me know your thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done relatively simply using [Seaborn's histplot function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# construct some sample data
ps1_phot = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'FLT': flt, 'MAG': np.random.randn(1000) + i}) for i, flt in enumerate('girz')])

# plot overlapping histograms
sns.histplot(ps1_phot.dropna(subset=['MAG']), x='MAG', hue='FLT')
```

Results in

[image: overlapped histogram]

Comment: I wanted to say thank you so much. I was stuck on this forever, and you were able to do this in two lines. This is amazing, and thank you for exposing me to Seaborn's histplot function!

Comment: I do want to ask how you got the colors? I also wanted to ask how you got the x axis. The Mag values should be between 14-26 and I am particularly confused on how you got negative values

Comment: No problem! Seaborn uses the names of the columns to get the labels for the axes and legend. The negative values are just due to the sample data I generated because you didn’t supply the complete data set.

Answer (score 0):

seaborn is the way to go. To plot distributions, you have several options in the seaborn library: sns.distplot(), sns.kdeplot(), sns.boxplot(), sns.histplot(). Personally I like using sns.distplot(), as it gives you options to display the histogram and the curve.